# More concise way of setting a counter, incrementing, and returning?

Tags: ruby, string-comparison

I'm working on a problem in which I want to compare two strings of equal length, char by char. For each index where the chars differ, I need to increment the counter by 1. Right now I have this:

```
def compute(strand1, strand2)
    raise ArgumentError, "Sequences are different lengths" unless strand1.length == strand2.length

    mutations = 0
    strand1.chars.each_with_index { |nucleotide, index| mutations += 1 if nucleotide != strand2[index] }
    mutations

    end
end
```

I'm new to this language but this feels very non-Ruby to me. Is there a one-liner that can consolidate the process of setting a counter, incrementing it, and then returning it?

I was thinking along the lines of selecting all chars that don't match up and then getting the size of the resulting array. However, from what I could tell, there is no `select_with_index` method. I was also looking into `inject` but can't seem to figure out how I would apply it in this scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the simplest answer is to just count the differences:

```
strand1.chars.zip(strand2.chars).count{|a, b| a != b}
```

Comment: This is arguably the best reading option, but `zip` takes O(2n) memory which makes this less applicable on large inputs.

Comment: @Nic, "less applicable" than what?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Than any of the other options mentioned here in abundance.

Comment: If memory usage is a concern I suppose you could use a lazy enumerable. Also, FWIW O(2n) == O(n).

Comment: I'm not sure about the lazy enumerable in this case. It will generate elements one by one but since it will keep previously allocated elements up to the point of executing `count` this should not give any advantage. Correct me if I'm wrong. From algorithm analysis perspective, O(2n) is indeed == O(n), but from applied perspective it will  still take twice the memory which is not to be kidding about.

Comment: I believe ruby lazy enumerators don't keep intermediate elements built up in memory after they've been consumed. Intermediate objects only live so long as their needed for the final computation then they become candidates for garbage collection. Regarding whether or not 2n memory is relevant: sometimes it matters and sometimes it doesn't. However, I was mostly commenting on the notation you chose... Big Oh analysis is a theoretical tool commonly used to argue why constant factors don't (asymptotically) matter, which appears to be the wrong tool for the application you're envisioning.

Comment: The point of being consumed is `count` call isn't it right? Meaning all lazily computed items will wait for that together. This is not a good scenario for using lazy computation since there is mostly allocation that takes place. Big O is a standard notation of describing time or space performance in CS. Not sure there is anything wrong with using that in current context.

Comment: Certainly nothing wrong with your big-oh usage. Regarding the lazy computation, checkout this code sample, I think it illustrates what I mean better than words do: http://repl.it/sVY

Comment: Well, the example illustrates that lazy computation helps when chaining list comprehensions. There is no arguing about that. It's just it doesn't help any of suggested solutions. All lazy does in this case is, paradoxically enough, extra work.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a number of one-liners:

`strand1.size.times.select { |index| strand1[index] != strand2[index] }.size`

This is not the best one since it generates an intermediary array up to O(n) in size.

`strand1.size.times.inject(0) { |sum, index| sum += 1  if strand1[index] != strand2[index]; sum }`

Does not take extra memory but is a bit hard to read.

`strand1.chars.each_with_index.count { |x, index| x != strand2[index] }`

I'd go with that. Kudos to [user12341234](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3277393/user12341234) for mentioning `count` which is this is built upon.

**Update**

Benchmarking on my machine gives different results from what @CarySwoveland gets:

```
                   user     system      total        real
mikej          4.080000   0.320000   4.400000 (  4.408245)
user12341234   3.790000   0.210000   4.000000 (  4.003349)
Nik            2.830000   0.170000   3.000000 (  3.008533)


                   user     system      total        real
mikej          3.590000   0.020000   3.610000 (  3.618018)
user12341234   4.040000   0.140000   4.180000 (  4.183357)
lazy user      4.250000   0.240000   4.490000 (  4.497161)
Nik            2.790000   0.010000   2.800000 (  2.808378)
```

This is not to point out my code as having better performance, but to mention that environment plays a great role in choosing any particular implementation approach.

I'm running this on native 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP x64 on 12-Core i7-3930K with enough RAM.

Comment: I suggest you write `(0..strand1.size)` as the enumerator `strand1.size.times`.  Also, `strand1.each_char.with_index` avoids the creation of the temporary array produced by `chars`.  What does "O(n) in size" mean?

Comment: Great pick! Edited my answer. In "O(n)" n is the size of input and here this means it will take more memory to accomodate up to n elements of the array. See [here](https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/) for Big O notation.

Comment: My point is that  `O(n)` is meaningless without defining `n`.  Isn't it clearer to just say "since it generates an intermediary array whose maximum size is the length of each string?", or better, considering that the size of that array is obvious, "since it generates an intermediary array".

Answer (score 2):

This is an just extended comment, so no upvotes please (downvotes are OK).

Gentlemen: start your engines!

**Test problem**

```
def random_string(n, selection)
  n.times.each_with_object('') { |_,s| s << selection.sample }
end

n = 5_000_000
a = ('a'..'e').to_a
s1 = random_string(n,a)
s2 = random_string(n,a)
```

**Benchmark code**

```
require 'benchmark'

Benchmark.bm(12) do |x|

  x.report('mikej') do
    s1.chars.each_with_index.inject(0) {|c,(n,i)| n==s2[i] ? c : c+1}
  end

  x.report('user12341234') do
    s1.chars.zip(s2.chars).count{|a,b| a != b }
  end

  x.report('lazy user') do
    s1.chars.zip(s2.chars).lazy.count{|a,b| a != b }
  end

  x.report('Nik') do
    s1.chars.each_with_index.count { |x,i| x != s2[i] }
  end
end
```

**Results**

```
mikej          6.220000   0.430000   6.650000 (  6.651575)
user12341234   6.600000   0.900000   7.500000 (  7.504499)
lazy user      7.460000   7.800000  15.260000 ( 15.255265)
Nik            6.140000   3.080000   9.220000 (  9.225023)

                  user     system      total        real
mikej          6.190000   0.470000   6.660000 (  6.662569)
user12341234   6.720000   0.500000   7.220000 (  7.223716)
lazy user      7.250000   7.110000  14.360000 ( 14.356845)
Nik            5.690000   0.920000   6.610000 (  6.621889)
```

[Edit: I added a `lazy` version of 'user12341234'. As is generally the case with `lazy` versions of enumerators, there is a tradeoff between the amount of memory used and execution time. I did several runs. Here I report the results of two typical ones. There was very little variability for 'mikej' and 'user12341234', somewhat more for `lazy user` and quite a bit for `Nik`.]

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but results on my machine look like this: 

```
                       user     system      total        real
    mikej          4.080000   0.320000   4.400000 (  4.408245)
    user12341234   3.790000   0.210000   4.000000 (  4.003349)
    Nik            2.830000   0.170000   3.000000 (  3.008533)
```

Comment: Sorry, is it possible to have formatted content in the comments?

Comment: @Nik, I don't think so.

Comment: Right. What environment are you running this on?

Comment: @Nik,my [main machine](http://media.news.harvard.edu/gazette/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Turing_Mark-I_380.jpg) is down, so I ran it on a three-year old Macbook Pro.

Comment: I edited my answer to include benchmark results on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

`inject` would indeed by a way to do this with a one-liner so you are on the right track:

```
strand1.chars.each_with_index.inject(0) { |count, (nucleotide, index)|
  nucleotide == strand2[index] ? count : count + 1 }
```

We start with an initial value of 0 and then if the 2 letters are the same we just return the current value of the accumulator value, if the letters are different we add 1.

Also, notice here that `each_with_index` is being called without a block. When called like this it returns an enumerator object. This lets us use one of the other enumerator methods (in this case `inject`) with the pairs of value and index returned by `each_with_index`, allowing the functionality of `each_with_index` and `inject` to be combined.

---

Edit: looking at it, [user12341234's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3277393/user12341234) solution is a nice way of doing it. Good use of `zip`! I'd probably go with that.

Comment: Yeah, his is pretty nice and concise. I appreciate your help though. `inject` makes much more sense to me now, and I wasn't aware you call a method without a block!

Comment: Yep, in the Ruby docs you'll often see a few different versions of the same method where there's a description of what the method does with and without a block. For another example take a look at the different ways a new Hash can be constructed: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Hash.html#method-c-new - in your own methods you write you can check if you were passed a block using `block_given?`